# Applying image to random object

Tags: xcode, swift, nsarray

I've created an NSArray with buttons and now I wish to apply an image to a randomly chosen button from that array;

```
let buttons:NSArray = [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10, button11, button12]
    let range: UInt32 = UInt32(buttons.count)
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))
    let buttonstring = buttons.objectAtIndex(randomNumber)

    buttonstring.image() = UIImage(named: "code2")
```

This last piece of code is where I wish to apply the image to the randomly chosen button. But it has an error saying;

> Cannot assign to value: function call returns immutable value

Comment: In which line you are getting the error?

Comment: What is the type of the button variables? Whatever type is it, the function `image()` appears to be used to get the image, not set it. Perhaps you should be calling `buttonstring.setImage(UIImage(named: "code2"))`

Comment: If `buttonX` are `UIButton` objects, -> @GaryMakin:s suggestion. Note however that the `.setImage(..)` method for `UIButton` also needs an argument `forState` (`setImage(_:forState)`), so Gary:s suggestion should be just slightly modified to `buttonstring.setImage(UIImage(named: "code2"), forState: .Normal)`.

Comment: @dfri, you are correct about the `forState` parameter an UIButton. But if the compiler wasn't complaining about `image()` not existing, I'm guessing that they're not UIButtons.

Comment: @GaryMakin You're right, possibly some custom class that the OP has forgotten to show us!

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota `buttonstring.image() = UIImage(named: "code2")`

Comment: @dfri They are UIButtons.

Comment: @dfri Your code worked, I wrote it with a small letter, my mistake. Thank you a lot - post your answer if you want me to check and upvote it :-)

Comment: @R.S If they are `UIButton` instances, and you haven't extended `UIButton` with a method, then the method `.image()` shouldn't exist. It seems Garys suggestion solved your problem, but out of interest, what version of Swift are you using? To allow for calling non-mutating function `.image()`? (which I cannot reproduce).

Comment: @R.S It's ok, just accept penatheboss:s answer below as it just says the same, no reason for me to add a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If buttonstring is a UIButton, you have to use something like this:

```
buttonstring.setImage(UIImage(named: "code2"), forState: .Normal)
```

Hope this helps.